# Does there exist a subspace of the Cantor set homeomorphic to the rationals?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am looking for a full explanation of the following two questions, as well as a rather hand-wavy intuitive argument (if one exists).

> Let $E$ be the set of endpoints in the Cantor set, $C$. Is it true that $E\cong\mathbb{Q}$?
>
> If not, does there exist some $X\subset C$ such that $X\cong\mathbb{Q}$?

[This paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1210.1008.pdf) mentions that the first question is true, then gives a short proof of the statement that a topological space $X$ can be embedded into $C$ if and only if $X$ is $T_0$, second-countable, and zero-dimensional, which, while certainly answering the second question, doesn't resolve (for me) why the image of such an embedding could be $E$.

Comment: You're not alone, there. The endpoints of the Cantor set are rational, but their structure is entirely different from the set of rationals. Moreover, the Cantor set contains many other rational numbers. But even that set is very different from the set of rational numbers, because, much like the Cantor set, but very unlike the set of rational numbers, it consists mainly of gaps, loosely speaking.

Comment: @ProfessorVector The homeomorphism is not required to be order-preserving. As each endpoint has infinitely many nearby endpoints on one side, it does not really matter that there is a gap on the other side.

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen Yes, I know, but... it feels different, I admit that I can't explain that in more formal terms. And there are rationals like $1/4$, $1/13$, $1/40$ and their sums which are not endpoints, and it's difficult for me to see exactly where in the Cantor set they are.

Comment: A fun nuke: show that *every* compact metric space is the continuous image of the Cantor set, and now think about $(0, 1)\cap \mathbb{Q}$ as a subset of the compact metric space $[0, 1]$ ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the family of all endpoints of intervals removed in the construction of the Cantor set is homeomorphic to the rationals. A quick way to see this is the following topological characterization of the rationals which can be found in

- *Sierpiński, W.*, [**Sur une propriété topologique des ensembles dénombrables denses en soi.**](https://eudml.org/doc/212608), Fundamenta Mathematicae 1, 11-16 (1920). [ZBL47.0175.03](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:47.0175.03).

> **Theorem.** Any countable metric space without isolated points is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$.

Calling this set of endpoints $Q$, it is clear that $Q$ is countable (there are only countably many intervals removed) and metric (as a subspace of $\mathbb R$). That $Q$ has no isolated points can be seen by noting that at stage $n$ in the construction of $C$ there intervals remaining all have length $3^{-n}$ (taking the zero-th step to be the closed unit interval $[0,1]$ of length $1 = 3^{-0}$). So if $x \in Q$ and $\varepsilon > 0$ is given, taking $n$ is large enough that $3^{-n} < \varepsilon$, then in the $n$th stage some interval of length $3^{-n}$ must have been removed from the left (or right) side of $x$ with its right (or left) endpoint within $\varepsilon$ of $x$.

Comment: Also see http://at.yorku.ca/p/a/c/a/25.pdf which explains the proof and goes into the Cantor set as well.

Comment: Thank you both for the answer and the proofs!